# QTP Script - Click On WebTable Cell - Works in IE but not in Chrome

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Writing automation script for a web application, there's a table,

Upon modification, user need to click on the cell to enable it.

1. Before user click on any cell, there's no childitem is detect ( try with childitem count with micclass - webEdit, webList, webElement - All return 0)
2. After user click on the cell, the cell will change to editable field - webedit/weblist -- at here the childitemcount become 1
3. Hence, click on the cell become a core process ( Open for suggestion if there's any workaround)

Currently I am clicking on a cell, input then click on the next cell, then repeat again. Here are the fragment of my code. The `Object.rows(row).cells(i).click` is not working in Chrome, but IE is doing correctly without any Issue.

**Tried:**

- Highlight the table - It's showing the correct table
- Print `row, i` after highlighted the table

  - IE -- it will be 1,0 ; 1,1 ; 1,2 and so on
  - Chrome -- it's failed at the first step, Error = General Run Error
- Change Value of row, i to be +1 both ( still not working )

**Code:**

```
row = 1  
rows = dictObject("WEBTBL_ACCDTL_FLOWTBL").GetROProperty("rows")
Arry_userInput = split(userinput,";")

'rows - 1 because of the header
If row <= rows-1 Then
    For i = 0 To Ubound(Arry_userInput) Step 1
        dictObject("WEBTBL_ACCDTL_FLOWTBL").highlight
        dictObject("WEBTBL_ACCDTL_FLOWTBL").Object.rows(row).cells(i).click 'Here Working in IE but not Chrome
        set currTxtBox = dictObject("WEBTBL_ACCDTL_FLOWTBL").ChildItem(row+1,i+1,"WebEdit",0)
        currTxtBox.Object.focus
        currTxtBox.Object.scrollIntoView    

        If i = 0 or i = 1 or i = 2 or i = 3 or i = 7 Then
            Call table_dropdown_set(currTxtBox,Arry_userInput(i))
        Else
            Call table_txtbox_set(currTxtBox,Arry_userInput(i))
        End If

        wait 1
    Next
    wait 1
    Msgbox "Input Process Done!"
Else 
    Msgbox "Please Trigger the button to add new row!"
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you're using `.Object` in order to access the cell, by doing this you're not utilizing UFT's full capabilities. Have you tried using the [`Cell`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.03/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Web/WEBPACKAGELib~WebTable.html#Cell) property? This was added in a recent version of UFT so you should check if it's available in the version you're using.

**Usage:**

```
Browser("B").Page("P").WebTable("WT").Cell(row, column).Click
```

Unlike the `ChildItem` function of `WebTable` the `Cell` returns the element of the cell itself and not the contents of the cell which I think is what you really need.